# breeze.js Cannot read property '_ctorRegistry' of undefined Error

Tags: javascript, breeze

I'm trying to create first entity for my entityManager but I recieved an error:

> Cannot read property '_ctorRegistry' of undefined

at line

> var ent1 = entityType.createEntity();

```
            var entityManager = new EntityManager("breeze/NorthwindIBModel");

            var entityType = new EntityType( {
                shortName: "input"
            });

            var info = new DataProperty( {
                name: "info",
                dataType: DataType.String,
                isNullable: true,
                maxLength: 20
            });

            entityType.addProperty(info);

            var ent1 = entityType.createEntity();
            ent1.info = 'this is info';
            entityManager.addEntity(ent1);
```

how to make first entity?

Comment: I don't know for sure but I don't think you should be creating a new entity type like you are.  Have you looked at the creating entities docs?  http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/creating-entities

Comment: @PW Kad, yes, I've read this doc. Still don't understand how to create new entity of new entityType in breeze. Second thought was to use entityManager.fetchMetadata().then(function(){}).fail(function(){}) but it also gives me error: "then is undifined". Which is strange because $q connected and works.

Comment: You should attach your new type to metadataStore. See your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651431/create-new-entity-with-new-entity-type-in-breeze for an answer

Comment: @Qvatra - this is one of three SO posts on this subject. Would you mind consolidating them, either by deleting or "closing" as "answered" and pointing people to the SO that should carry the conversation? Thanks.