# create new entity with new entity type in breeze

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I'm writing cordova + angular + breeze app where text info from  element should be stored in the cash of browser that wraps the app. [Accordind to the docs](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/creating-entities) to do so, first I need to create new entity type in breeze. I do the following:

```
var entityManager = new breeze.EntityManager("api/Northwind");
var newType = new breeze.EntityType({
    shortName: "input"
});
```

Next I'm trying to create new entity of this type:

```
var newEntity = newType.createEntity();
```

This fails with message: "TypeError: Cannot read property '_ctorRegistry' of undefined"

Is seems to be very basic functionality of breeze but I can't get it work for 2 days already. Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: As the accepted answer indicates, there are at least 3 problems here. (1) the new type must be added to a `MetadataStore` ... almost certainly the one that belongs to the manager (`manager.metadataStore`) and (2) the new type should have some properties ... at least a key property. Now Breeze will think you can persist this to the server so you better guard against that. I find myself wondering "Why is Qvatra creating a pretend entity that can't be persisted?". You may have a good reason but it seems a dubious move on it face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After created new EntityType, you should attach it to metadataStore to create entities of new type. Your code should look:

```
var metadataStore = new breeze.MetadataStore();
entityManager= new breeze.EntityManager({
            serviceName: "api/db",
            metadataStore: metadataStore
        });

// if you call fetchMetadata()
entityManager.fetchMetadata().then(function(){
    var newType = new breeze.EntityType({
        shortName: "input"
    });

    entityManager.metadataStore.addEntityType(newType);

    newType.createEntity(...);
    // ...
});

//or just use var metadataStore
var newType = new breeze.EntityType({
    shortName: "input"
});

entityManager.metadataStore.addEntityType(newType);

newType.createEntity(...);
// ...
```